# Recursive stacks not saving changes in hashmap

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, iteration, file-handling

My code is the following

```
public class FileHandler {

public static void main(String... args) {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/TJF22/Desktop/Simple Network 1/alpha 15");
    mapFiles(file);
}

public static HashMap<String,File[]> mapFiles(File directory){
    File[] inputContents = directory.listFiles();
    HashMap<String,File[]> fileMap= new HashMap<String,File[]>();
    for (File content : inputContents){
        if (content.isDirectory()){
            File[] nestedContents = content.listFiles();
            if (areAllFiles(nestedContents)){
                String key = content.getPath();
                fileMap.put(key,nestedContents);
            } else {
                mapFiles(content);
            }
        }
    }
    return fileMap;
}

public static boolean areAllFiles(File[] directory){
    for (File files : directory){
        if (!files.isFile()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What I want to do is to be able to recursively go through a given input file directory and for the files contained in this input directory:

-if the file is a directory and all this directories contents are files, then associate the directory name as a key to the file names in it (as values) and store into fileMap

-if the file is a directory and it contains other directories within it, then keep going until you find a directory within it with only files in it

-if the file is a file, then ignore it

**But my problem is that when I return fileMap, the HashMap, I get an empty HashMap because for some reason, the key,value pairs that I stored are not being saved. Any help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the existing HashMap instead of re-creating the map each time you re-call `mapFiles`.

```
public static HashMap<String,File[]> mapFiles(File directory){
    HashMap<String,File[]> fileMap = new HashMap<String,File[]>();
    fileMap = mapFiles_Recursive(directory, fileMap);
    return fileMap;
}


private static HashMap<String,File[]> mapFiles_Recursive(File directory, HashMap<String,File[]> fileMap) {
    File[] inputContents = directory.listFiles();
    for (File content : inputContents){
        if (content.isDirectory()){
            File[] nestedContents = content.listFiles();
            if (areAllFiles(nestedContents)){
                String key = content.getPath();
                fileMap.put(key,nestedContents);
            } else {
                mapFiles(content, fileMap);
            }
        }
    }
    return fileMap;
}
```

Comment: DOH, that's such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: If you liked my answer, remember to mark as your selected answer. To help others out, on the site. Regards -